# .htaccess force 404 and prevent directory listing

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to force a 404 error if someone tries to access any directory in my root directory (/var/www) provided the directory name contains .git?

I.e if someone tried to access `http://mysite.com/site.git`, it would show a 404 page?

Furthermore, how could I prevent directory listing in the same file?

I am using Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu).

Thanks,

Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite, you can put these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.git$ - [R=404,L]
```

Or, you can replace the brackets with a `[F,L]` to return a 403 Forbidden instead.

Comment: It appears that it's still happening. When navigating to the ...com/site.git, it shows a directory listing.

Comment: I don't think so, where would I set those?

Comment: @max_ Take a look at the [AllowOverride docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride). It'll be inside the `<Directory>` block in your server/vhost config.

Comment: I set it to All and restarted the apache server, but the file still doesn't work: http://u.maxk.me/JVqQ - /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Comment: @max_ Oh, is there a reason you have `Multiviews` turned on? try removing that from `Options`

Comment: Still no difference i'm afraid.

Comment: @max_ Dunno then, that rule works for me when I put that in a blank htaccess file on a freshly installed apache 2.2 server.

Comment: @max_ Did you do `-Multiviews`? What happens if you replace the rule with `RewriteRule (.*) /blah/$1 [R,L]`? (it should redirect you to a bogus URL). If that doesn't work then you know your htaccess is being ignored completely, otherwise something else is wrong

Comment: MultiViews didn't make a difference. 'blah' redirect works perfectly though!

Comment: @max_ Then it's not an htaccess issue, there must be something that's intercepting the `.git` requests and handling them before it gets to mod_rewrite.

Comment: Fair enough, would you happen to know a way around this, or what's causing it?